# What does the "@" symbol do in a ngRequest

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I am seeing for example that we can do something like this in AngularJS ngResource
`$resource('seeks/:seekId', { seekId: '@_id'});` but I am not sure what the `@` symbol does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From AngularJS resources docs:

> $resource(url, [paramDefaults], [actions], options);
>
> [paramDefaults] > If the parameter value is prefixed with @ then the value for that
>   parameter will be extracted from the corresponding property on the
>   data object (provided when calling an action method). For example, if
>   the defaultParam object is {someParam: '@someProp'} then the value of
>   someParam will be data.someProp.

What that means:

Supposing that our server returns:

```
{_id: 123, otherField: 'someValue'}
```

for this GET request: `'/seekId/123'`

If we want to retrieve this data using ngResource we can do it like this:

```
var SeeksResource = $resource('/seeks/:seekId');
SeeksResource.get({seekId: 123}, function (seek){
    // GET request: /seekId/123
    // Server response: {_id: 123, otherField: 'someValue'}
});
```

but when we want to do an update:

```
var SeeksResource = $resource('/seeks/:seekId', null, {update: {method:'PUT'}});
SeeksResource.update({_id: 123, otherField: 'otherValue'}, function (seek) {
    // PUT: /seekId
    // Server return: ERROR because seekId was not provided, there is nothing about :seekId anywhere in our request
});
```

we can fix this using @:

```
var SeeksResource = $resource('/seeks/:seekId', {seekId: '@_id'}, {update: {method:'PUT'}});
SeeksResource.update({_id: 123, otherField: 'otherValue'}, function (seek) {
    // PUT: /seekId/123
    // Server return: {_id: 123, otherField: 'someValue'}
});
```

Now works because when the request is made $resource service is getting the value for :seekId from the "_id" property from the data object provided.

Is also good to know that @ symbol will be used by $resource service only for non-GET requests.

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/wnzr721o/

Comment: thanks. I did end up finding this in the documentation a few minutes later. It was hidden well in there. I should have thought to do a search for the "@" character first. Douh!